# Unable to install Plugins in Eclipse (jpbm)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jbpm

I have a major problem with installing plugins in eclipse. I'm using ubuntu 10.04 64 bit and I installed:

Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.6.0
Build id: I20100608-0911

(**Not** by using the apt-get, via apt-get I get galileo, but that version didn't work as well)

The Plugin I want to install is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%203/jbpm-jpdl-3.2.7/ I have to use this plugin because its compatible with alresco (dms)

I tried to install the plugin via dropin and the normal way:

`Help->Install new Software-> Add -> Archive -> select the downloaded *.jar`.

When I hit OK, I get the following error message:

`"Could not find jar:file:/home/xyxyx/jbpm.jar"`

I tried to solve it by extracting the jar but no success. Putting the jar into the plugins folder and changing permissions won't help! I also tried different versions of eclipse on several systems. No success!

I have been looking for a solution all day! I tried some advice I found on stackoverflow. I don't use a proxy. I changed the update system to classic! Now I don't know what to do anymore.

Anything special I have to configure before I use eclipse on ubuntu besides installing the JDK?

Comment: "I also tried different versions of eclipse on several systems", have you tried other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the installed using the following command:

```
  java -jar jbpm-installer-3.2.7.jar
```

On the other hand, you may want to use [JBoss IDE](http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/) which has integrated support for jBPM.

Comment: I decided to use http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%203/jbpm-jpdl-3.2.7/ because the alfresco wiki recommends the use of it. I can with JBoss Ide if the output fits alfresco.

Comment: My bad, looks like I'm using the wrong versions! I'm new to jbpm, jboss etc. :)